# Spring Boot - Liquibase doesn't create the DATABASECHANGELOG table

Tags: database, spring-boot, liquibase

I have a **Spring Boot** application.
And my **Liquibase** doesn't create the `DATABASECHANGELOG` table.
It proceeds the changelog and after that throws an error.
Any ideas what could be wrong?
Something is missing?

error:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'addressbook.DATABASECHANGELOG' doesn't exist
```

config:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/addressbook?characterEncoding=UTF-8
    username: root
    password: root
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    change-log: "classpath:db/liquibase-changelog.yml"
```

changelog:

```
databaseChangeLog:
- changeSet:
    id: 1
    author: me
    changes:
    - sqlFile:
        path: sql/20181025_startup.sql
        relativeToChangelogFile: true
        stripComments: true
- changeSet:
    id: 2
    author: me
    changes:
    - sqlFile:
        path: sql/20181026_create_table_contacts.sql
        relativeToChangelogFile: true
        stripComments: true
```

dependencies:

```
gradleVersion=4.10.2
springCloudVersion=Finchley.SR2
springBootVersion=2.0.6.RELEASE
mysqlVersion=5.1.47
liquibaseVersion=3.6.2
```

Comment: `databasechangelog` table is usually created inside default schema. It may be overridden via `spring.liquibase.default-schema=default` Spring's property. Seems like the Liquibase looks for the table in wrong location while it may already exist

Comment: unfortunately not, after your hint I get this error: `Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'default'`

Comment: hmm that's a placeholder. You have to specify the default MySQL schema name for the database you've created, assume `addressbook` is